# Migrating from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-migration

I need to migrate SQL Server 2000 databases to SQL Server 2008 and need to formalize a generic strategy for this migration. Need a ordered list of activities which should be done to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resources - Migration from SQL 2000/SQL2005 to SQL 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/blakhani/archive/2008/12/27/resources-migration-from-sql-2000-sql2005-to-sql-2008.aspx)

[Migrating from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic578433-391-1.aspx)

Comment: Hi - +1 for the resources. I am looking for a verified plan which can be executed straight as I am unfortunately not given enough time for this.

Comment: So you are looking for a one-size-fits-all document that outlines all of the steps you need to migrate from 2000 to 2008?  I don't think such a thing exists, because every environment is different, and the things you need to prepare for during migration can be totally different from mine.  You will need to explain to the people who allocate your time that this isn't a Next > Next wizard and you *will* need prep time to learn what issues you might come across.  A good first start is running the SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Advisor on your 2000 instance: http://is.gd/4ZJhA